# Читабельность форума

Tags: предложение, правила, ответы

Замечаю в последнее время, что форум некоторыми своими частями перестает быть читабельным. Это проявляется в том, что некоторые участники сильно стараются добавить деталей в ответ (накрутчики репы), получается портянка на страницу-две, абсолютно ненужная и неструктурированая для анализа.

Все это выливается в то, что основного ответа нет, а альтернативные ответы остаются далеко позади. Да и желания что-то писать в вопрос нет, т.к. нет желания все это читать.

Начал тенденцию, конечно @VladD, продолжает ее @Vlad from Moscow. Сейчас уже постепенно подтягиваются другие (поняли в чем фишка).

Предлагаю для таких ответов вводить регламент:

1. Содержание, как минимум
2. Краткие тезисы, предваряющие дальнейшие детали, если деталей больше четверти страницы.
3. Детали, по возможности - под спойлер

т.е. суть ответа - выносим на поверхность, альтернативы выделяем и связываем с остальным контентом.

**Кстати**, с подачи @Krom Stern: понимаю, что не все авторы умеют "рефакторить свои мысли на бумаге", поэтому предлагаю просто добавить в список тревог к ответу соответствующий пункт, например: "Ответ слишком громоздкий, чтобы оценить его адекватность"

Comment: Абсолютно согласен, портянки на три страницы, которые обсасывают тему со всех сторон это явно перебор. Причём я говорил на эту тему с  @VladD, но он не согласен

Comment: Цитата из справки "Этот сайт посвящен исключительно получению ответов. **Это не форум** для дискуссий."

Comment: Правильно, в ответе вообще должен быть только код, причем без комментариев. Можно использовать сокращения, чтобы дополнительно сэкономить трафик читателей и место в базах данных SO. Достоверно известно, что вопросы здесь задают только программисты с 20-летним стажем, им ответ будет понятен сразу и без разжевывания.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ага, и ни в коем случае они не должны узнать теоретической базы стоящей за конкретным решением, а то не дай бог начнут строить аналогии и решать подобные задачи самостоятельно, спрашивать перестанут

Comment: каким образом детализированный ответ с пояснениями позволяет как Вы выразились накрутить репутацию?

Comment: "Этот сайт посвящен исключительно получению ответов" -- @Krom Ваша т.з. непонятна. Если Вы это предлагаете в качестве контраргумента, то подумайте над разницей между фразами "получению ответов" и "получению знаний".

Comment: "Можно использовать сокращения, чтобы дополнительно сэкономить трафик" -- @Nick Volynkin: бессмысленный троллинг

Comment: @mega мой аргумент выделен жирным - хватит называть SO форумом )

Comment: "каким образом детализированный ответ с пояснениями позволяет как Вы выразились накрутить репутацию?" -- @Bald56rus: читайте внимательно предложение, ничего не имею против детализированного ответа.

Comment: @Krom Stern, по прежнему т.з. непонятна. Вы задумались над разницей между этими фразами?

Comment: @mega перечитал, вопрос все равно остается причем здесь детализированный ответ и накрутка репы? можете привести пример большого ответа в котором под тоннами подробностей теряется смысл, и насколько я понял наверху висят те ответы которые имеют больший рейтинг, напишите краткий ответ который поддержит большинство и Ваш ответ будет Выше, про спойлер согласен что он иногда бывает необходим но его же нет

Comment: @Bald56rus, такие ответы оценивают не за правильность, а за старания. Чтобы оценить его правильность, автор предлагает переварить читателю все его доводы, которые обычно уходят вглубь либо известного мануала, либо к собственным рассуждениям на эту тему, рождающих на свет обычно что-то банальное. Это обычная татика для накрутки, примерно из той же серии, когда для эффекта на профессора, надевают очки-нулевки. Поэтому я и предлагаю ввести регламент на такие рассуждения с самим собой. Даже не столько для предотвращения накрутки, сколько для полезности топика.

Comment: точно автор вопроса ставит галочку у ответа ничего не говорит (помоему это в справке пишут), а вот Вы как профессионал можете согласиться с ответом либо опровергнуть, ***Плюс/Минус***, ответы @VladD большие, детальные но они сверху не потому что стоит галочка а потому что другие считают что он *лучший*

Comment: "такие ответы оценивают не за правильность, а за старания." - странный довод

Comment: "но они сверху не потому что стоит галочка а потому что другие считают что он лучший" -- @VladD здесь по сути работает - могу только предполагать откуда у него столько времени на форум. Но он первый именно потому, что вносит огромный вклад в базу SO. Это немного разные вещи. Большинство, кто отдает ему предпочтения - это новички, которые любят почитать о программировании на русском. Я не берусь оценивать уровень его знаний, это не цель вопроса, т.к. по вышеизложенной причине, только 1-2% информации, которую излагают эти люди, вообще воспринимается при беглом чтении.

Comment: @mega если Вы такие ответы оцениваете *за старания* - не делайте так. Оценивайте то что понимаете и с чем согласны.

Comment: я отношу себя тоже к категории новичков, и соглашусь с Вами что не все может быть понятно сразу, но такие ответы меня толкают на изучение новых вещей, вот с чем полностью с Вами согласен так это в необходимости спойлера, а в остальном, заставлять людей вносящих такой огромный вклад в развитие не только сообщества но и нового поколения программистов.

Comment: "если Вы такие ответы оцениваете за старания - не делайте так" -- поэтому я их обычно не оцениваю. Как кто-то уже говорил - "пройти мимо" - тоже оценка, и довольно полезная.

Comment: @Mike а если они спрашивать перестанут, это вообще беда! Мы все потеряем источник дохода, нам ведь за ответы зарплату платят.

Comment: а кто оценивать то будет? в чем принципиальное отличие от оценить сейчас поставив ***+/-***?

Comment: Ну Вы же видите, что с желающими оценить проблем нет. Кстати, обновил вопрос.

Comment: т.е. Вы хотите увеличить нагрузку на модератов ввиду того что Вы не хотите читать длинный ответ сами, так и не понял принципиальной разницы между оценить сейчас

Comment: "Вы хотите увеличить нагрузку на модератов" -- не на модераторов, а на сообщество. Но, в целом - да, конечно: хочу, чтобы форум был более читабельнее, и хочу, конечно же оценивать "портянки", иметь на это возможности. )

Comment: я Вас понимаю так: Вы видите длинный ответ, кидаете тревогу ибо сами ленитесь читать, дальше данный ответ попадает в очередь проверок, где он может попасть на проверку таким людям как я(имеется ввиду менее опытный в большинстве это будет так, и опять таки IMHO), я увижу данный вопрос и начну сомневаться а правильный ли это ответ, и ситуация будет как с *опросником*, стоит одному указать эту причину и обязательно найдется еще n человек которые согласятся, станет ли лучше?! сомневаюсь, хуже запросто

Comment: Вы так и не сказали где начинается *Портянка* а где так должно быть

Comment: "он может попасть на проверку таким людям как я..." -- Это будет очень хорошо, если он попадет в **отдельную** очередь, т.к. ее будут смотреть люди именно с т.з. подачи материала читателю, а не правильности ответа. Правильность ответа в дальнейшем будут уже оценивать эксперты. Это все очень логично, мне нравится.

Comment: вангую: Ответ может быть плохим с точки зрения подачи материала читателю, но правильным по сути и наоборот.

Comment: "Ответ может быть плохим с точки зрения подачи материала читателю, но правильным по сути и наоборот" -- о чем вангуете? Точно так же дела обстоят и сейчас: ответ может решать задачу, но несоответствовать каким-то правилам SO и наоборот, и такой ответ будет удален, если так посчитает большинство, и это нормально. Вы этим хотели покритиковать модераторский аппарат, или что, каким боком ваше вангование тут?

Comment: @mega: Нет, я _не_ работаю здесь. И не получаю здесь зарплату.

Comment: "Нет, я не работаю здесь. И не получаю здесь зарплату." -- не помню, чтобы я об этом писал или спрашивал :)

Answer (score 12):

Длинные и **детальные ответы это хорошо**. Они разжевывают материал, описывают подробности, затрагивают смежные области.

Что можно посоветовать тем, кто пишет развернутые ответы - **добавлять краткую выжимку в начале ответа**, а подробности разворачивать ниже.

Указывайте на это в комментариях, в крайнем случае предлагайте правки, если нужно.

Comment: "Они разжевывают материал, описывают подробности, затрагивают смежные области" -- сейчас получается как раз так, что разжевывания и описания заполоняют весь ответ, а главная мысль топика подо всем этим теряется.

Comment: @mega а что есть главная мысль топика, как не дать ответ? Качественный развернутый ответ. Ответ, который скажет не только "что" но и "как" и "почему".

Comment: Качественный и развернутый - это как раз мое предложение, а Вы пока не определились со своей т.з., по всей видимости.

Comment: «Краткость — сестра таланта», говорят, это сказал какой-то известный мужик ;), может стоит прислушаться?

Comment: @ixSci краткость это хорошо, но не всегда полезно, можно дать ответ который породит новый вопрос, а можно дать ответ как это делает VladD и научить что более важно(IMHO), впрочем об этом уже писали выше в коментах

Comment: @Bald56rus, новый вопрос  — новый ответ. Все счастливы. Я не против того, когда раскрывают ответ чуть шире, чем есть вопрос. Я против того, что начинают давать чрезмерно общий ответ на вполне конкретный вопрос, длиной в четыре покрывала. Мне лень читать столько текста, чтобы проверить, правилен ли он.

Comment: @ixSci если вам лень читать - ну так не читайте, значит этот ответ не для вас. Плюсаните однострочник из кода без объяснения. А кто-то простынку прочитает и поймет, и проплюсует это дело.

Comment: @KromStern, проблема в том, что в этой портянке может быть ошибка. А вот найти ошибку может кто-то либо на уровне, либо уровнем выше отвечающего. А плюсы действительно лепят все кому не лень, и если написано много текста, «значит чувак разбирается». А это может быть ошибкой.

Comment: @mega поэтому я тоже не леплю плюсов до прочтения. И всем советую!

Comment: "если вам лень читать - ну так не читайте, значит этот ответ не для вас" -- это вирусная тактика. За "многобукв" читателей гораздо больше, чем "за знания", поэтому такая тактика грозит потерей авторитетности ресурса.

Comment: @mega Википедию тоже закроем, за "слишкомногобукв"

Comment: у Википедии совершенно другая политика, там нет Q&A и нет авторства

Comment: В Википедии, кстати, с этим все отлично. Посмотрите, как там оформляются длинные страницы.

Answer (score 3):

Хотя я полностью с Вами согласен, что портянки зачастую мешают. Я считаю, что это не изменить и вводить какой-либо регламент тут просто-напросто вредно. Потому что иногда портянка нужна, действительно нужна. Чаще нет, как мне кажется, но случаи бывают разные.

Кроме того, создание портянок это одна из свобод пользователей, посягательство на которую может быть воспринято в штыки. Поэтому, на мой взгляд, можно лишь ввести рекомендации, но никак не правила.

Comment: Дальше будет только хуже. Тенденция уже намечена. Я не предлагаю запрещать портянки, я предлагаю заставить автора правильно их оформлять.

Comment: @mega что есть *портянка*?, даешь новый холивар аля что такое *опросник*

Comment: "что есть портянка?" -- Это уже другой вопрос. Можете задать отдельно, пообсуждаем. Поверьте, я бы в шапке выложил примеры, если бы хотел поспорить на эту тему. Сейчас обсуждаем портянку с т.з. оценки вопроса **любым** читателем - каждый сам может выделить для себя такие ответы. Для меня - любой ответ, о котором я подумаю: "слишком длинно" и/или "бесполезно". Впрочем, я уже указал людей, ответы которых чаще всего я воспринимаю именно так.